# Does it have or has?

Tags: questions

Generally we use "hads* with he , she , and it.

So which one is correct to say ?

Does this phone has / have xyz function ?

Does his father has / have a car ?

Answer (score 13):

The answer in both instances is 'have'. It is ungrammatical to use 'has' in questions that begin with 'Do' or 'Does'. In these types of questions the verb 'do' is conjugated based on whether the noun is first, second or third person (eg Do I, Do you or , Does he). The 'have' part of the question is not conjugated and appears as the bare infinitive regardless of the person of the noun.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've got the same doubts about if ungrammatical say 'does has' instead of 'does have'. In my mind show me up immediately the verb to be, and then I think in basic structure (he she it -does and has / I you we and they - Do and have).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133852)